# Convert NSNotification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] to Enum

Tags: ios, swift

Using NSNumber from NSNotification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]

In Objective C I would do the following

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0
                    options:(curveValue.intValue << 16)
```

Swift will not allow me to do the same even though the bitshift operator is the same. I would like to get the enum raw value which is equivalent

UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut            = 0 << 16,

UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn               = 1 << 16,

UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut              = 2 << 16,

UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear               = 3 << 16,

update

---

I am not sure if the below approach is correct , it seems to work

```
 var animationCurve : UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut
 info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey].getValue(&animationCurve)


 UIView.animateWithDuration(durationValue.doubleValue,
        delay: 0,
        options: animationCurve,
        animations: {self.navigationController.toolbar.frame = myRect},
        completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks, your update version works.

Answer (score 3):

In Beta-5

```
UIViewAnimationOptions.fromRaw(
    UInt(
        ( p.userInfo[ UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey ] as NSNumber ).unsignedIntValue << 16
    )
)!
```

Comment: Is the need to shift by 16 bits documented anywhere?

Comment: Works in Xcode 6.0 final release as well. The shift is defined in the Objective C code.

Comment: Has this been updated since Xcode 6 and Swift came out of beta? It seems overly-complicated.

Comment: @KristopherJohnson https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/uiviewanimationoptioncurveeasein?language=swift

Answer (score 1):

You have to init a UIViewAnimationOptions with the rawValue like this:

`UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
    delay: 0,
    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.init(rawValue:UInt(curveValue.intValue << 16)),`

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you need?

```
UIViewAnimationCurve.fromRaw(Int(hereGoesYourStuff))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it may we be a solution but it is not quite complete. I think I may have resolved this

Comment: Since the value of UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey is 7 which is not documented in the sdk, UIViewAnimationCurve.fromRaw(7) will return nil

Answer (score -1):

```
let animationKey = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as UInt
UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationKey)
```

Comment: if animationKey is not 0-3, the init method returns nil which is incorrect since animationKey is 7 on ios 7+