# How to force a raw value of 7 into a UIViewAnimationCurve enum?

Tags: enums, swift, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimation-curve

The key [`UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621613-keyboardanimationcurveuserinfoke) in the userInfo dictionary of a `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` contains an `Int` with the value `7`.

Now I need to pass this `Int` into `UIView.setAnimationCurve(<here>)`. I tried to create the required UIViewAnimationCurve enum like this `UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: 7)`. Because the raw value `7` is undocumented, the result is always `nil`.

It works fine this way in Objective-C. Any idea how to get this animation curve from the notification into a UIView animation using Swift?

**Update:**
As pointed out by Martin, this is no longer a problem since Xcode 6.3.

From the [Xcode 6.3 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW392):

> Imported `NS_ENUM` types with undocumented values, such as `UIViewAnimationCurve`, can now be converted from their raw integer values using the `init(rawValue:)` initializer without being reset to `nil`. Code that used `unsafeBitCast` as a workaround for this issue can be written to use the raw value initializer.

Comment: Note that this problem does not exist anymore in Swift 1.2, as documented in the Xcode 6.3 release notes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I figured it out, but I'm not sure if this is the way it's supposed to be done.

```
let animationCurve = unsafeBitCast(7, UIViewAnimationCurve.self)
UIView.setAnimationCurve(animationCurve)
```

**Update:** The solution contained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24041737/4097) works as well.

```
var animationCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut
NSNumber(integer: 7).getValue(&animationCurve)
```