# How to determine if undocumented value for NS_ENUM with Swift 1.2

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

For instance, following NS_Enum is defined...

```c
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Type) {
  TypeNone = 0,
  TypeA = 1,
}
```

```
var x = 2
if let type: Type = Type(rawValue: x) {
  // Swift 1.2 executes this block.
}
else {
  // Previous swift executes this block.
}
```

How can I determine if x is defined on NS_ENUM or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *assume* this is a consequence of the following change in Swift 1.2, documented in
the [Xcode 6.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-DontLinkElementID_23):

> Imported NS_ENUM types with undocumented values, such as
>   `UIViewAnimationCurve`, can now be converted from their raw integer
>   values using the `init(rawValue:)` initializer without being reset to
>   `nil`. Code that used `unsafeBitCast` as a workaround for this issue can
>   be written to use the raw value initializer. For example:
>
> ```
> let animationCurve =  
>      unsafeBitCast(userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey].integerValue,
>      UIViewAnimationCurve.self)
> ```
>
> can now be written instead as:
>
> ```
> let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue:  
>     userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey].integerValue)!
> ```

The problem (if I understand it correctly) was that

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIViewAnimationCurve) { ... }
```

defined only 4 possible enumeration values, but could in fact take other
(undocumented) values as well. This made some nasty workarounds necessary, see for example

- [How to force a raw value of 7 into a UIViewAnimationCurve enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168413/how-to-force-a-raw-value-of-7-into-a-uiviewanimationcurve-enum)

To solve this problem, Swift 1.2 does now allow the creation of 
enumeration variables with *arbitrary* raw values (of the underlying
integer type), **if the enumeration is imported from an `NS_ENUM` 
definition.**

As a consequence, it is *not possible* to check programmatically if
a "raw value" is one of the defined values in the `NS_ENUM` definition.

Comment: More of the amazing Swift syntax woes. More and more reasons to prefer it over ObjC/C.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```c
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Type) {
    TypeZero = 0,
    TypeOne = 1,
    TypeTwo = 2,
    TypeUnexpected = INT_MAX
};
```

```swift
switch Type(rawValue: 3) ?? .unexpected {
case .zero:
    // Handle type zero
    ...
case .one:
    // Handle type one
    ...
case .two:
    // Handle type two
    ...
default:
    // Handle unexpected types
    ...
}
```