# Enum defined with NS_ENUM's rawValue initializer doesn't fail

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I have an Objective-C file with an enum defined like:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, State) {
  State_ACTIVE = 0,
  State_PENDING = 1,
  State_CANCELED = 2
};
```

In my swift code, if I do `let state = State(rawValue: 100)`, usually this should return `nil`, since it's a failable initializer. However, when the enum is declared as such (with `NS_ENUM`), initialization succeeds, and there's no indication that that is an invalid enum value. Is this a bug in Xcode, or working as intended?

Comment: That is intended, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570133/how-to-determine-if-undocumented-value-for-ns-enum-with-swift-1-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended behavior.  For any `NS_ENUM`s bridged to Swift the constructor will never return `nil`.

Try it with some other enums in the iOS SDK bridged to Swift with unexpected values.  They will all return non-nil, even for a `rawValue` that is not defined by the enum:

```
UITableViewCellStyle(rawValue: 7) // "Optional(__C.UITableViewCellStyle)"
UITableViewCellAccessoryType(rawValue: 9999) // "Optional(__C.UITableViewCellAccessoryType)"
```

or, with `unsafeBitCast`:

```
unsafeBitCast(42, UITableViewCellEditingStyle.self) // "Optional(__C.UITableViewCellStyle)"
```

Martin R pointed out that this is documented in
the [Xcode 6.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-DontLinkElementID_23):

> Imported NS_ENUM types with undocumented values, such as
>   `UIViewAnimationCurve`, can now be converted from their raw integer
>   values using the `init(rawValue:)` initializer without being reset to
>   `nil`. Code that used `unsafeBitCast` as a workaround for this issue can
>   be written to use the raw value initializer. For example:
>
> ```
> let animationCurve =  
>      unsafeBitCast(userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey].integerValue,
>      UIViewAnimationCurve.self)
> ```
>
> can now be written instead as:
>
> ```
> let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue:  
>     userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey].integerValue)!
> ```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? Or is there an explanation for this behavior that I'm missing?

Comment: @Ned edited my answer to point to the Xcode release notes where this is documented.

Comment: I'd also check out the [OptionSetType protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define an extra initialiser in an `extension` of the enumeration to implement the (Swift-like) behaviour to suit your needs:

```
extension State
{
    static var allRawCases: [Int]
    {
        var array = [Int]()
        switch State.ACTIVE
        {
        case .ACTIVE:
           array.append(State.ACTIVE.rawValue)
           fallthrough
        case .CANCELED:
           array.append(State.CANCELED.rawValue)
           fallthrough
        case .PENDING:
           array.append(State.PENDING.rawValue)
        }
        return array
    }
}

extension State
{
    init?(raw: Int)
    {
       guard State.allRawCases.contains(raw) else
       {
          return nil
       }
       self = State(rawValue: raw)!
    }
}
```

Pros:

1. If you add / remove enum case in Objective-c code the compiler will display an error and you will adopt the code.
2. New constructor behaves as default constructor of a native swift enumeration (without associated values).
3. In next piece of code it's better to have a `nil` variable instead of an "invalid" value. This value leads to a crash in swift 3 + Xcode 10
   project.

   ```
   // intValue differs from raw enumeration values e.g 100 
   guard let state = State(rawValue: intValue) else
   {
       return
   }

   switch state
   {
   case .ACTIVE:
       // do active staff            
   case .CANCELED:
       // do canceled staff
   case .PENDING:
       // do pending staff
   }
   ```

Cons:

1. The `allRawCases` property grows proportionally to the number of elements in the Objective-c enumeration.
2. Debugging of a large enumeration hardly will make you happy.