# Swift equivalent to set multiple values to a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am currently using a cocoapod which was written in objective c.
In the example they show something like that:

```
options.allowedSwipeDirections = MDCSwipeDirectionLeft | MDCSwipeDirectionRight;
```

I don't even know what these sort of variables are called but I already tried the following in Swift:

```
options.allowedSwipeDirections = MDCSwipeDirection.Left | MDCSwipeDirection.Right
```

But the compiler says `No '|' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'MDCSwipeDirection'`

How would I do this in Swift?

Edit:

It looks like this is not an `OptionSet` as stated in some answers, her is the declaration:

```
/*!
 * Contains the directions on which the swipe will be recognized
 * Must be set using a OR operator (like MDCSwipeDirectionUp | MDCSwipeDirectionDown)
 */
@property (nonatomic, assign) MDCSwipeDirection allowedSwipeDirections;
```

and it is used like that:

```
_allowedSwipeDirections = MDCSwipeDirectionLeft | MDCSwipeDirectionRight;
```

Comment: try to use it like  `[.Left, . Right]`

Comment: I have removed my previous comment. MDCSwipeDirection seems to come from https://github.com/modocache/MDCSwipeToChoose where is its defined in ObjC as an NS_ENUM, not NS_OPTIONS.

Comment: @MartinR Actually it is a fork: https://github.com/clsource/MDCSwipeToChoose but the only differency should be the possibility to swipe up and down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MDCSwipeDirection` is (unfortunately) defined in Objective-C
as an `NS_ENUM` and not as `NS_OPTIONS`:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MDCSwipeDirection) {
    MDCSwipeDirectionNone = 1,
    MDCSwipeDirectionLeft = 2,
    MDCSwipeDirectionRight = 4,
    MDCSwipeDirectionUp = 8,
    MDCSwipeDirectionDown = 16
};
```

It is therefore imported to Swift as a simple `enum` and not
as an `OptionSetType`:

```
public enum MDCSwipeDirection : Int {

    case None = 1
    case Left = 2
    case Right = 4
    case Up = 8
    case Down = 16
}
```

Therefore you have to juggle with `rawValue` for `enum <-> Int`
conversions:

```
let allowedSwipeDirections =  MDCSwipeDirection(rawValue: MDCSwipeDirection.Left.rawValue | MDCSwipeDirection.Right.rawValue)!
```

Note that the forced unwrap cannot fail, see for example
[How to determine if undocumented value for NS_ENUM with Swift 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570133/how-to-determine-if-undocumented-value-for-ns-enum-with-swift-1-2):

> ... Swift 1.2 does now allow the creation of enumeration variables with
>   arbitrary raw values (of the underlying integer type), **if the
>   enumeration is imported from an `NS_ENUM` definition.**

---

*If* you change the Objective-C definition to

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, MDCSwipeDirection) {
    MDCSwipeDirectionNone = 1,
    MDCSwipeDirectionLeft = 2,
    MDCSwipeDirectionRight = 4,
    MDCSwipeDirectionUp = 8,
    MDCSwipeDirectionDown = 16
};
```

*then* it is imported as

```
public struct MDCSwipeDirection : OptionSetType {
    public init(rawValue: Int)

    public static var None: MDCSwipeDirection { get }
    public static var Left: MDCSwipeDirection { get }
    public static var Right: MDCSwipeDirection { get }
    public static var Up: MDCSwipeDirection { get }
    public static var Down: MDCSwipeDirection { get }
}
```

and you can simply write

```
let allowedDirections : MDCSwipeDirection = [ .Left, .Right ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that this `MDCSwipeDirection` is a structure conforming to [`OptionsSetType`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/OptionSetType/), e.g. something along

```
struct SomeOptionSetType : OptionSetType {
    let rawValue : Int
    init(rawValue:Int){ self.rawValue = rawValue}

    static let Left = SomeOptionSetType(rawValue:1)
    static let Right = SomeOptionSetType(rawValue:2)
}
```

in which case you can access several "cases" (static properties; options) simply using array-like listing `[..., ...]`:

```
var myChoices : SomeOptionSetType = [.Left, .Right]
```

Applied to your case, specifically

```
options.allowedSwipeDirections = [.Left, .Right]
```

As we can assume that `allowedSwipeDirections` property is of type `MDCSwipeDirection`, hence you can omit this type when grouping your options array-style.

Comment: I am not the Downvoter but this gives me `Contextual type 'MDCSwipeDirection' cannot be used with array literal`

Comment: @Ybrin As [MartinR](https://github.com/modocache/MDCSwipeToChoose/blob/master/MDCSwipeToChoose/Public/State/MDCSwipeDirection.h) pointed out. In this case, the `NS_ENUM` will just be imported to Swift as an `Int`-type enumeration with cases `.Left` (rawvalue 0) and `.Right` (rawvalue 1). If this is the case, I don't know how to allow several allowed swipe cases (as neatly done using `OptionsSetType` conforming types), as `options.allowedSwipeDirections` simply expect only `.Left` or `.Right`, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

You can set them like an array in Swift:

```
options.allowedSwipeDirections = [MDCSwipeDirection.Left, MDCSwipeDirection.Right]
```

Or shorthand:

```
options.allowedSwipeDirections = [.Left, .Right]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an option set

```
options.allowedSwipeDirections = [MDCSwipeDirection.Left, MDCSwipeDirection.Right]
```

Have a look at Option Sets [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)